# Building libQGLViewer error: cannot find lqglviewer-qt5

Tags: qt, qt5, cgal, qt5.6, qglviewer

I am trying to build the [lQGLViewer](http://libqglviewer.com/) in order to compile CGAL demos. 
I am following primarily the steps [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxzaW5naHN1a2hyYWp8Z3g6MThiNjRkNjhhMWY0ZjgyYw) and

I have installed qt 5.6.0. as well as the dependencies freeglut3 freeglut3-dev binutils-gold g++ libglew-dev mesa-common-dev build-essential libeigen3-dev libboost-all-dev libmpfr-dev libgmp-dev libtbb-dev zlib1g-dev

However, when I try to build the lQGLViewer with QT Creator [3.6.1] I receive the error:

`cannot find -lQGLViwer-qt5`

The same error is with both versions 2.6.4 and 2.7.1 of lQGLViewer

The entire output is available [here](https://pastebin.com/iRp1rMSy)

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Is this due to the QT version I have installed?

Comment: Does't ubuntu provide a libqglviewer-dev package? `apt show libcgal-demo` may have relevant suggestions in "Suggests:".

Answer (score 0):

You'd rather follow those instructions for libQGLViewer : http://libqglviewer.com/compilation.html You can also try setting NO_QT_VERSION_SUFFIX to TRUE
And if you really can't install it, CGAL demos don't need libQGLViewer since 4.12.

Comment: Indeed only a couple of the CGAL demos require libQGLViewer I tried also with the instructions from libQGLViewer.com however still had issues. However it turns out libqglviewer-dev can be installed from the repositories

Comment: The 3D demos needed libQGLViewer before 4.13. Since then, QGLViewer has been forked and integrated. It is 4.13, which is still in beta, not 4.12, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install libqglviewer-dev from the ubuntu repositories. This allowed me to compile some of the 3d demos from CGAL

Answer (score 0):

I don't think xenial supports qt5 package. However, this site gives you access to all available versions.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=qglviewer

For installing libqglviewer-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libqglviewer-dev
```